# how to make pandas read excel with double quotes in string

Tags: excel, pandas, format, quotes

I am trying to read an excel with pandas. A column has string values with double quotes within it. When I print the df, the double quotes are shown as x94. How can I fix this?

i.e. the string in the excel is:

[DSEGCODE]="g"

and it's read as

[DSEGCODE]=x94gx94

Comment: The character is probably not a double quote but the [cancel character](https://charbase.com/0094-unicode-cancel-character)

Comment: Do you mean it's a cancel character in the excel file? I can see a double quote, am I missing something?

Comment: The [cancel character](https://charbase.com/0094-unicode-cancel-character) looks like [double quote](https://charbase.com/201d-unicode-right-double-quotation-mark) and the python escape code `u'\x94'` seems to what you have, no?

Comment: Yes that's true. Any hints on how to actually type a double quote in excel without getting the escape character in python?

Comment: It's an excel problem. Python reads the contents of Excel cells, that's all. Can you share a such excel file, please?

Comment: I see. I just found out that I can change the actual character into another without new issue. Thank you!